# Индексы PRIMARY и UNIQUE KEY для одного и того же поля

Tags: mysql

Есть ли какой-либо смысл в следующем построении индексов?..

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
```

P.S. Движок MyISAM.

**UPD**

В книге "MySQL. Оптимизация производительности" я нашла следующее:

> Фактически в MyISAM отсутствуют структурные различия между пер- вичным
>   ключом и любым другим индексом. Первичный ключ является просто
>   уникальным индексом, не допускающим пустых значений под названием
>   PRIMARY.

Получается, смысла в этом точно нет. А влияет ли это как-либо на производительность? Т.е. MyISAM создаст два индекса для этого поля `id` или всё же один?

Comment: не вижу, какой тут может быть смысл...`PRIMARY KEY` подразумевает `UNIQUE`...

Comment: *влияет ли это как-либо на производительность?* да. *Т.е. MyISAM создаст два индекса для этого поля id или всё же один?* два.